# Swift 5 Firebase queryOrderedBy String value

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

is it possible to query after the child value if its a string? In alphabetically order?
Doesnt matter whether it is descending or ascending.
e.g. under the key, each reference has the assigned name of the follower, and I want to order all the followers alphabetically.
Only manage to query it ordered by an integer unfortunately. (INCLUDING PAGINATION)

If this doesnt work, is there a way to query ordered by key? e.g. I have key 1 "-edasMmaed" and key 2 "-deLkdnw" etc and that if do paginate I start after the last value?
I haven't found anything useful unfortunately.

Kind regards

Edit: This is for the first part of the question

[image]

[image]

EDIT 2:

```
        var query = Ref().databaseFollowingForUser(uid: userId, type: type).queryOrderedByKey()
    
    if let latestUserFollowers = uid, latestUserFollowers != 0 {
        query = query.queryEnding(atValue: latestUserFollowers).queryLimited(toLast: limit)
    } else {
        query = query.queryLimited(toLast: limit)
    }

    query.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
```

With this code I receive the first 10 results (limit is defined as 10)
everbody from ID: 276 through ID: 18. (starting at holgerhagerson and ending at manni85)

Now I want to paginate and load more which I am not able yet.

The passed uid is the uid of the latest fetched user which is "18", manni85

BIG EDIT: I managed to order it by keys. Reading your answers regarding keys are always saved as strings, I realized my mistake and are now able to do it properly.

Big thank you!

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you're asking.  Can you edit your question to show the database structure you want to query, and the code for whichever of these [sorting and filtering operations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data) you've already tried?

Comment: Sure! I have added an image of the structure

Comment: I either want to get it ordered by numbers (doesnt need to be descending, I have heard that firebase does it alphalexically but as long as I am able to properly paginate it it doesnt matter to me! And thanks in Advance!

Comment: "get it ordered by numbers" What is "it" in here? And what are the "numbers" you want to order on? It is much more likely we can help if you show exactly what you're trying to do (e.g. by showing the code you already have) and what output you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keys in the Firebase Realtime Database are stored (and sorted) as strings. Even if they look like numbers to you, Firebase will store (and sort) them as strings.

This means that the `2`, `3`, `4`, etc in your screenshot are actually `"2"`, `"3"`, `"4"` etc. This affects how they are ordered, as strings are ordered [lexicographically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order) and in that order these keys will show up as `"3"`, `"30"`, `"4"`, `"44"`, `"5"`, etc.

If you want to use keys that you can sort numerically, take these steps:

1. Prefix keys with a short non-numeric prefix, to prevent Firebase interpreting them as an array.
2. Use a fixed length for the numbers in all keys, prefixing the value with zeroes or spaces as needed.

When combined, your keys would show up as:

```
"key_003": ...,
"key_004": ...,
...
"key_008": ...,
"key_016": ...,
"key_018": ...,
"key_030": ...,
"key_044": ...
```

Which you can now reliably sort when you query `/FOLLOW/Follower/2` by calling `queryOrderedByKey()`.

Comment: Hey thanks! Its fore for me if its ordered lexicographically! How would I achieve that? As I cannot change the database now as its already live with an app

Comment: What I describe is how the database works. There's no option to change that.

Comment: No I meant how can I paginate it as ordered lexicographically. That I get 3, 30, 4, 44 and then if I can't to load more I get 5, 55 etc

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Can you edit your question to: 1) show the code that you tried already with the APIs I linked in my comment to your question and in my answer? 2) the result you got from the database with that? 3) the result you expect to get instead?